# Dynamically nested angular material menu implemented but one time one menu list will not be open

Tags: angular

I have implemented dynamic multi level menu list using Angular material but the problem is one time one menu list will not be open. suppose menu list is just like below if I click on menu list1 then menu list1 items show then after if I click on menu list2 then menu list2 open but menu list1 close.

```
menu list1 
    menu 1
    menu 2
menu list2  
    menu 1
    menu 2

// menu list code 

<a mat-list-item [ngStyle]="{'padding-left': (depth * 12) + 'px'}" (click)="onItemSelected(item)"
   [ngClass]="{'active': item.route ? router.isActive(item.route, true): false, 'expanded': expanded}"
   class="menu-list-item">
  <mat-icon class="routeIcon">{{item.iconName}}</mat-icon>
  {{item.displayName}}
  <span fxFlex *ngIf="item.children && item.children.length">
    <span fxFlex></span>
    <mat-icon [@indicatorRotate]="expanded ? 'expanded': 'collapsed'">
      expand_more
    </mat-icon>
  </span>
</a>
<div *ngIf="expanded">
  <app-menu-list-item *ngFor="let child of item.children" [item]="child" [depth]="depth+1">
  </app-menu-list-item>
</div>
```